# I am trying to stop advertisements on youtube videos which i getting through youtube data api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to stop advertisement coming on YouTube videos through data API , May be their some premium services so that we can we stop YouTube advertisements .

Comment: YouTube is free because of ads on videos. Blocking them is against their Terms of Service.

Comment: So , normally we have a premium account , there we can ignore advertisements , Same way can we have some paid access for YouTube-data-API  so we can ignore advertisements.

Comment: I haven't heard about such a paying feature.